# Best way to upload media to Shopware 6 programmatically?

Tags: file-upload, upload, media, shopware, shopware6

What would be the best way to upload media in Shopware 6 programmatically? (eg: category media) . I'm able to create categories through the sync API but I don"t know how to attach images to the categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a media object. I'm using v1/_action/sync for that
2. Upload the image. v1/_action/media/{uuid}/upload?extension=jpg&fileName=%s

If you want to do it within a plugin or etc. please see my answer in this thread:
[Media creation via php in shppware 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410548/media-creation-via-php-in-shppware-6/63410717#63410717)

Comment: Can we upload multiple images at a same time using api?